# Lambda Function to return different value using parameters

Tags: python, lambda, python-datetime

I would like to use a `lambda` function to return values.  This could be handled in a function, however would prefer the use of lambda for this exercise.  In general, I want to have the `lambda` return either a date or 0 by passing a second parameter.

```
import datetime
none_func=lambda x: 0 if x is None else x
print(none_func(None))
print(none_func(7))
print(none_func(datetime.datetime(2020,1,1)))
### Here, update the lambda function to take an additional parameters, like returns a date if None as well
none_func=lambda x: datetime.datetime(1900,1,1) if x is None else x
print(none_func(None))
print(none_func(7))
```

### Updated for clarification:

I would like to convert the coalesce function to a `lambda`.

```
def coalesce(x,return_schema='int'):
    if x is None and return_schema=='int': return 0
    elif x is None and return_schema=='date': return datetime.datetime(1900,1,1)
    else: return x

print(coalesce(7))
print(coalesce(None))
print(coalesce(None,return_schema='date'))
print(coalesce(datetime.datetime.today(),return_schema='date'))
```

Comment: Lambdas can take multiple parameters, what is the problem?

Comment: What issue are you facing? What is your expected output?

Comment: I think your main question is how to write a lambda expression with optional parameters. Am I right?

Comment: Surprisingly, it is possible: `>>> f = lambda a, b=0 : a + b   ;>>> f(5)   ;5    >>> f(5, 2)    ;7 `

Comment: You have the technical answer below... but it's totally unpythonic - it's using a lambda for no good reason (lambdas are supposed to be _anonymous_ functions) and turns a simple readable code into a complex one-liner that requires twice much effort to read and understand.

Comment: I agree with you.  Later to realize its best just to use a defined function instead.  For the most part, I was trying to understand how to use a lambda to replace it, however, as you pointed out a labda in this instance would make for a difficult read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function would be a better option, but if you want to convert it to lambda you can try something like this:

```
import datetime

f = lambda x,return_schema="int": 0  if x is None and return_schema=='int' else ( datetime.datetime(1900,1,1) if x is None and return_schema=='date' else x)
print(f(7))
print(f(None))
print(f(None, return_schema='date'))
print(f(datetime.datetime.today(), return_schema='date'))
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I agree, the function would be a better option, but i think this is only to get practice in how you can build lambda expressions and try other ways.

Comment: Yes that's what I understand too - but it's still usefull for python newbies to be warned that it's not what they should do ;-)

Comment: I added that in the response header, thanks for remark that important point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something along the lines of:

```py
func = lambda x, y: 'default' if (x is None or y is None) else x

func(1, 2)        # returns 1
func(None, 1)     # returns 'default'
func(1, None)     # returns 'default'
func(None, None)  # returns 'default'
```

Or if you only want to do something based on the second parameter just change the if statement to test the value of that.